# Find distance of overlapping squares

Tags: euclidean-geometry

How to find distance center to center  from [square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1r3G.png) $1$ to square $3$, if we need overlap area is $15.46 mm^2$. if we know each side of the square is $6.9 mm$.

Firstly I find the distance is $9.3 mm$ but it's wrong. Anyone can help to solve this question ?
[image]

Comment: Why do you think $9.3mm$ is wrong? I get $9.3188mm$.

Answer (score 1):

$$L=6.9mm$$
$$A_o=15.46mm^2$$
The width of a single overlap region is thus $x=A_o/L$.
The distance between the centers is the original distance, $L/2 + L + L/2$ minus twice the width of an overlap region: $L/2 + L + L/2 - 2 x = 9.3188mm$.

So it seems to me like your answer was correct.

Are you sure that $15.46mm^2$ is the area of a single overlap region, as indicated on your figure, and not of the total overlap?